# Function calls with different api input parameters returning the same output everytime, Flask api

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, api, flask

I have a function which returns me a vector.

```
def class_vector(*categories):
    all_categories = categories
    model = Word2Vec.load(r"C:\Users\vector.model")
    my_dict = dict({})
    for idx, key in enumerate(model.wv.vocab):
        my_dict[key] = model.wv[key]
                   
    categories_vectors = dict({})
        
    for i in all_categories:
        if i.lower() in my_dict.keys():
            categories_vectors[i] = my_dict[i]
                  
    average_vector = np.mean(list(categories_vectors.values()), axis =0)
    average_vector =  average_vector.reshape(1, -1)

    return average_vector
```

Now I call this function and test the vectors generated for 2 different input combinations:

```
test 1 = class_vector("apple", "banana")
test 2 = class_vector("grapes", "papaya", "lemon")
```

This works perfectly and returns me a new vector for every new combination of fruits. The above function is in a .py file called vectors_list.py

Now I want to build an api that takes the fruit names as input from a user and use the `class_vector` function to return the computed vectors.

Api code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from vector_list import class_vector

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def status():
    fruits = request.args.getlist("param")
    str_fruits = ",".join(fruits)
    returned_vec = class_vector(*str_fruits )
    return str(returned_vec)
```

Now I do `flask run` from cmd &  run few tests

```
Test 1: `curl "http://localhost:5000?param=apple&param=banana"`
Test 2: `curl "http://localhost:5000?param=grapes&param=papaya&param=lemon"`
```

This returns me  the same vector for every new combination of fruits that I send as param to call the api. This is wrong and I want to understand why this is happening. Am I not calling the function correctly? Any suggestions

Comment: Why do you do `str_fruits = ",".join(fruits)`?

Comment: To convert it into a string because request.args.getlist returns a list and the function class_vector takes only string inputs

Comment: You already have a list of strings in `fruits`, so you can use it in the next call: `class_vector(*fruits)`.

Comment: Wow!It worked. Thank you so much. Can you tell me why `str_fruits = ",".join(fruits)` was making the function return the same output everytime

Comment: Posted details as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join your list of strings returned from `request.args.getlist`. Remove `str_fruits = ",".join(fruits)` and use `class_vector(*fruits)`:

```py
@app.route('/')
def status():
    fruits = request.args.getlist('param')
    returned_vec = class_vector(*fruits)
    return str(returned_vec)
```

Pay attention, that your `class_vector` function accepts variable arguments `def class_vector(*categories):`, and expects to receive a collection of parameters. Now, when you do join, you eventually call `class_vector` as follows: `class_vector('a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', ',', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a')` instead of `class_vector('apple', 'banana')`. This happens because with `*str_fruits` you unpack a string to a collection of characters.

Comment: This works perfectly but I am still not able to understand why. If I just return `str(fruits)` from the api, I will get something like this as output ['apple', 'banana']. If I directly try to pass this output to my class_vector function by creating a new object `test 3 = class_vector(["apple", "banana"])` this returns an error hence I used `str_fruits = ",".join(fruits)` to convert `["apple", "banana"]` into comma separated strings to pass it to the class_vector function. Can you please explain how the list brackets are not causing an issue when I do `returned_vec = class_vector(*fruits)`

Comment: I understand now that `str_fruits = ",".join(fruits)` was wrong as it formed 1 string but I want to know how the class_vector function is able to process `["apple", "banana"]` as  `class_vector('apple', 'banana')` from the api call

Comment: @Erich You unpack `str_fruits` when you call `class_vector(*str_fruits)`. Do you see `*`? That means that any collection (a list or a string of characters) gets split into separate pieces and passed as separate arguments to `class_vector`.

Comment: I completely got that part. Let's eliminate this line `str_fruits = ",".join(fruits)` as it is clearly wrong. Now, I am passing `class_vector(*fruits)` and I want to understand how the class_vector function is able to process `["apple", "banana"]` as `class_vector('apple', 'banana')` by just doing `*fruits`. There is a knowledge gap from my end so will appreciate any explanation or reference examples if possible

Comment: @Erich It looks like that. Have a look at arguments unpacking mechanism in Python. There is a set of examples here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/.

Comment: Thank you so much. This example answered my question